# Determining the direction of a turn?

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to turn an object clockwise or counter-clockwise. A couple of integers (from 0 -> 7) represent the direction that object is looking to (eg. left, leftup, up, upright, right, ...). Adding +1 to the current direction of the object turns it clockwise, substracting -1 turns it counter-clockwise.

*If I want the object to turn to a certain direction (= integer), how do I determine the minimum amount of turns necessary?*

Currently I'm using this way of thinking :

```
int minimumRequiredTurns = min(abs(currentDirection.intvalue - goalDirection.intvalue),
                       8 - abs(currentDirection.intvalue - goalDirection.intvalue));
```

Is it possible to do it without a `min` statement?

Comment: what do the 8 directions stand for? `(left,up,right,...)` - this implies only four directions. please clarify

Comment: should not it be int `minimumRequiredTurns = min(abs(currentDirection.intvalue - goalDirection.intvalue), 8 - abs(currentDirection.intvalue - goalDirection.intvalue));`

Comment: you are right, tafa. WeaselFox, it's actually left, leftup, up, upright, right, ...).

Comment: why?  Why not use the min statement if that is the clearest way to express it?

Comment: How does knowing the minimum required turns help you decide which direction to turn? If you want to avoid repeating the calculation, you should return both number of turns and direction.

Comment: I forgot to change the title Caleb, it's for determining the minimum required turns really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

`(1-(abs(abs(currentDirection.intvalue - goalDirection.intvalue)/(n/2)-1)))*(n/2)`

should do the trick, where `n` is the number of possible directions.

In order to have integer only calculations transform this to

`(n/2)-abs(abs(currentDirection.intvalue - goalDirection.intvalue)-(n/2))`

Explanation: Using the hat function to generate the map:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
5 -> 3
6 -> 2
7 -> 1
```

Comment: Edited it so that it conforms with the notation of OP

Comment: I didn't want to be slow if anybody had the same idea :) Thx

Comment: Azrael, it doesn't seem to be working for me if I only have 4 directions instead of 8. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you replace the 4s by 2s? Edit: I updated the answer to take an arbitrary number of directions into account.

Comment: I'll retry but I did that, yes.

Comment: One thing that you need to take care of is that the computation is in floating points, even though the end result is an integer. But if it works for 8 then it should work for 4 as well.

Comment: It doesn't work yet because dividing by `(n/2)` gets rounded (since we're working with integers... I'm gonna eat now but thanks for the amazing work already!

Comment: I modified the answer again to provide you with an integer only calculation.

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to get rid of the abs you could use some bit hacking to make it even more awesome. Maybe after work I have time to edit the answer.

Comment: I've tested it for different n values, and only uneven n values do not work. This is not a problem at all, since an uneven amount of orientations is not likely to happen :)

Comment: Well uneven values will not work with this formula. I thought that was obvious :) You would need to switch to float to make it work.

Comment: I used your solution so I picked your question as best answer :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't like the "min", you could use a lookup table.

```
int minRequiredTurns[8][8] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2,
    2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3,
    /* and so on... */
};
```

Comment: The problem with this is that, if I add subdirection, the table will be useless.

Comment: @Korion: To be honest, the current solution is jst fine too.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly, a much better design would be to **use vectors to represent directions**; treat the "direction" as a pair of numbers `(x,y)` so that `x` represents the horizontal direction, `y` represents the vertical.

So `(1,0)` would represent facing right; `(0,1)` would represent facing up; `(-1, 0)` would be facing left; `(1,1)` would be facing up-right; etc.

---

Then you can just use the normal vector-based solution to your problem:  Take the direction you're facing, and the direction you want to face, and take the [cross-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the two.

```
result = x1y2 - x2y1
```

If the result is positive, rotate counter-clockwise; if the result is negative, rotate clockwise *(this works because of the [right-hand rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition) that defines cross-products)*.

Note that this approach generalizes trivially to allow arbitrary directions, not just horizontal/vertical/diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

First, force a positive difference, then force to be between  0 and N/2 *(0 and 4)*:

```
N=8
diff = (new-old+N)%N;
turns = diff - (diff>N/2 ? N/2 : 0)
```

Comment: It's enough to make OP run screaming into the arms of 'min' :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int N = 8, turns = abs(current-goal);
if (turns > N/2) turns = N-turns;
```

But I don't understand why you don't want the min-statement...

Comment: Maybe it's a little contrived, but you could imagine having to implement this on some really limited device that didn't support branching and you could only use arithmetic, or where you really needed to avoid branching for performance reasons.

Comment: Sure this works, smarinov, but it's not exactly what I'm after. I wanted something along the lines of Azrael's answer or gcbenison's answer. Just arithmetic, as short as possible.

Comment: @Korion My bad, I have somehow completely passed by the relevant part of your question.

Comment: Hey it's certainly not your fault. I have a history of asking non-clear questions :D.

Answer (score 1):

No `min`, no `abs`, one expression, no division:

```
turns = ((((goalDirection + 8 - currentDirection) % 8) + 4) % 8) - 4
```

How it works: the innermost expression `(goalDirection + 8 - currentDirection)` is the same as given by AShelley; number of required turns in the clockwise direction.  The outermost expression shifts this to its equivalent in [-4..+3]

Comment: Amazing! Only problem is that the result can be negative, so you need `abs` anyways. At the moment I'm pretty sure it works... Thanks again! When I'm sure it works you'll be rewarded best answer.